# DBPedia Sparql Endpoint: keyword OPTIONAL

Tags: sparql, rdf, option-type, dbpedia, endpoint

I'm trying to run the following SPARQL query:

```sql
SELECT ?band, ?genre
WHERE
{
      ?band a umbel-rc:Band_MusicGroup.
      OPTIONAL{?band dbo:genre ?genre}.
}
```

but in the result there are no bands for which a `dbo:genre` is not defined (such as Coldplay [look here](http://dbpedia.org/page/Coldplay)).
Optional does not work in DBpedia?

Comment: @StanislavKralin What does your comment mean? The `10 000` is the default limit of the Virtuoso triple store. If somebody wnat's to get more data, `LIMIT` in combination with `OFFSET` is the way to go. (And to more formally correct also `ORDER BY`)

Comment: @AKSW, you have read my comment before I delete it :-). I suppose that Coldplay was "filtered out" from the results due to this limit.

Comment: :D alright. Ok, maybe then I misunderstood the question. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank's to @StanislavKralin I understand now that you might be confused by missing data in the resultset, e.g. Coldplay. The short answer here is that the Virtuoso triple store on which DBpedia is deployed has a default resultset size limit of `10000`, i.e. at most 10000 rows will be returned with a single query. If you want to get more results you have to use something that's often referred to as pagination, i.e. for each `chunk` you append

`ORDER BY ?band LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 10000*chunk`

Comment: There is this error: "Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Variable 'genre' is used in the query result set but not assigned"

Comment: Wait a second, I guess I misunderstood your question. You want to have all bands and its genre right? And you're wondering why some bands do not occur in your list?

Comment: Ok, then forget my first answer and have a look at the edited answer.

Comment: And now? What's the problem? My answer explains that your query is correct and does what you want. Please read again and understand that you get only 10000 rows back. Btu maybe I still misunderstand the question.

Comment: The number of bands is < 10000, thus you should get all the bands and optionally the genre.

Comment: Ok, cool. the number of bands is < 10000, but most bands have multiple genres. that's why you have to use pagination here.

Comment: With chunk=4 i have this error: "Virtuoso 22023 Error SR353: Sorted TOP clause specifies more then 50000 rows to sort. Only 40000 are allowed. Either decrease the offset and/or row count or use a scrollable cursor". What is scrollable cursors?

Comment: That's another limitation of Virtuoso resp. a parameter that can be increased in the config file)...a workaround is to put everything except `LIMIT/OFFSET` in a sub-`SELECT` query: `SELECT ?band ?genre {
{
SELECT ?band ?genre
WHERE
{
      ?band a umbel-rc:Band_MusicGroup.
      OPTIONAL{?band dbo:genre ?genre}.
}
order by ?band
}
}
limit 10000
offset 40000`